# Python 3.7 - ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python and trying to run a simple plot using the following code -

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset.hist()
plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error:
ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting.

I alraedy have pandas, numpy and matplotlib installed.

thanks.

Comment: check all dependency install on your machine.
Python (>= 2.7 or >= 3.4)
NumPy (>= 1.7.1)
setuptools
dateutil (>= 2.1)
pyparsing
libpng (>= 1.2)
pytz
FreeType (>= 2.3)
cycler (>= 0.10.0)
six
backports.functools_lru_cache (for Python 2.7 only)
subprocess32 (for Python 2.7 only, on Linux and macOS only)
kiwisolver (>= 1.0.0)

Comment: Always use `python3.7 -m pip install` to be sure that you're using the right version of python with pip,

Comment: `dataset.hist()` where is dataset to plot? `

Comment: on cmd check :
`python3 -c 'import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__, matplotlib.__file__)'`

Comment: @Roshan you mean `python3.7`. The problem is probably exactly that `python`, `python3` and `python3.7` are all different.

Comment: check it like `python -c 'import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__, matplotlib.__file__)'`
if only one version of python is installed

Comment: @Roshan What Andras said. When diagnosing issues like this it pays to be _very_ specific about the version of python.